# Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 can't pair with Bluetooth keyboard after update to 4.2.2

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, bluetooth, external-keyboard, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

Updated last night. Tablet can't find the keyboard when Bluetooth is turned on and tablet is visible.
This is the keyboard that came with the tablet in the student edition. I can't find anyone with this problem yet except in version 4.3. But this is 4.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by going to the Bluetooth settings screen, then holding down the Bluetooth button on the back of my keyboard for about 5-10 seconds.

After that, the keyboard showed up on the available devices and it allowed me to pair it with my Tab 2.

Comment: To clarify what this process does - holding down the button clears device pairings from the keyboard, and puts the keyboard back into discovery mode for the tablet to detect.